# Get ng-model validation status in Dart code

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When I use

```dart
<input type='text' maxlength='25' required ng-model='ctrl.inputValue'>
```

Angular adds several classes like `ng-valid`, `ng-invalid`, `ng-dirty`, `ng-pristine` to the element that allow showing visual indicators about the validation result.

Is there a way to these status in Dart code?

Comment: a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I have just looked in to this:

Take the following code (Form and names are important!):

```html
<div test>
    <form name="myForm">
         <input type='text' name="myInput" maxlength='25' required ng-model='ctrl.inputValue'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then the following directive/controller/component:

```dart
@NgController (
selector: "[test]",
publishAs: "ctrl"
)
class TestController {
  String inputValue;
  Scope thisScope;
  TestController (Scope this.thisScope) {
    thisScope.$watch("ctrl.inputValue", () { 
      NgModel inputModel = thisScope["myForm"]["myInput"];
      print(inputModel.invalid);
    });
  }
}
```

This will output whether the model is valid or not.

View documentation for NgModel here for other fields:
http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.directive/NgModel.html