# Fine-grained error messages in Angular Dart forms

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have the following form with some simple validation rules:

```dart
<form name="signup_form" novalidate ng-submit="ctrl.signupForm()">
  <div class="row">
    <input placeholder="Username"
        name="username"
        ng-model="ctrl.username"
        required
        ng-minLength=3
        ng-maxLength=8>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="signup_form['username'].dirty &&
      signup_form['username'].invalid">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would like to display specific error messages for `required`, `ng-minLength` and `ng-maxLength`, but I'm not having success being able to drill down into `signup_form['username'].errors` to get the specific error.

I can access the `errors` map just fine in the controller, it is in the markup that I cannot get a handle on the specific error. I would like to be able to do roughly something like this:

```dart
<div ng-show="signup_form['username'].errors['minlength'].invalid>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I.e., something like the following in angularJS:

```dart
<div ng-show="signup_form.username.$error.required">This field is required</div>
```

Comment: as a start you might take a look at a similar question I asked a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812728

Comment: The above code works fine for me. The only thing which is missing is that you did not include the `ng-hide` definition.

`<style> .ng-hide { display: none }</style>`

Comment: Hmmm. Misko, the `errors` map does not work correctly in the view. For instance, adding `<div>{{signup_form['username'].errors['required'] != null}}</div><div>{{signup_form['username'].errors['minlength'] != null}}</div><div>{{signup_form['username'].errors['maxlength'] != null}}</div>` results in the first `<div>` showing `true` and the other two showing `false` no matter what the value of the input.

Comment: I again updated my answer. I found a solution that I find good enough.

Comment: This changed a bit in Angular 0.9.10, so I updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

A working example for

Inspired by [this filter](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/771/files#diff-c93a7d69419d77d82f78b68848c5fbfeR4) I tried this approach again

**Angular 0.9.9**

```dart
@NgFilter(name: 'errors')
class ErrorFilter {
  call(val) {
    if(val != null) {
      return val.map.keys;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and in the markup

```dart
{{signup_form['username'].errors | errors}}
```

**EDIT for Angular 0.9.10**

```dart
@NgFilter(name: 'errors')
class ErrorFilter {
  call(val) {
    if(val != null) {
      return val.keys;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and in the markup

```dart
{{signup_form['username'].errorStates | errors}}
```

I learned from the discussions I have observed in the AngularDart Github repo that better solutions are on their way.

**related open issue**
When this https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/771 is landed
hopefully better solutions are possible.

Comment: Gunter, I can get the errors in the controller just fine. It is in the HTML where this isn't working. For instance, if I add  `{{signup_form['username'].errors}}` to the markup, it always displays `{required: [Instance of 'NgModel']}`.

Comment: Shailen, I got it (took a bit), I'm working on it but I only got a solution where you need a custom getter on the controller (ugly). (I don't like the new change detection at all).

Comment: I updated the question to clarify as well. Thank you for your help, Gunter.

Comment: The markup for direct access would be `signup_form['username'].errors.keys` but Angular (0.9.9) doesn't update the view when `keys` changes.

Comment: That is correct. The `keys` are not updated, which explains why they key always shows up as `required` in my example.

Comment: Actually the `keys` are updated, but the view isn't updated to reflect the changes (just to be sure we talk about the same thing). In another use case it was suggested to use a filter like `{{somelist | json}}` but this doesn't work here either.