# AngularDart custom model validation

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart

I was wondering if anyone had an example of implementing custom model validation in AngularDart or Angular2 for Dart.  I have been reading the docs and the few SO posts that exist, but I am not grasping how validation is applied.  I did find the NgValidator class in the AngularDart api, but there are no examples of how to implement in dart or html.

I am also wondering if you can access the NgModel object in Dart.  There is this post - [Get ng-model validation status in Dart code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812728/get-ng-model-validation-status-in-dart-code?lq=1), but it is for an old version of AngularDart and didn't work with components when I tried it.  I didn't see an obvious way to get at directive objects through the 'scope' object.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I guess I just needed a little more time on this issue, but at least here is an answer to the first part of my question. I went into 'ng_model_validators.dart' to see how the other model validators were being implemented.  I successfully implemented the following for a simple username length checker:

```
@Decorator(selector: '[ng-model][ng-username]')
class NgModelUsernameValidator implements NgValidator {

    final String name = 'ng-username';

    NgModelUsernameValidator(NgModel ngModel) {
        ngModel.addValidator(this);
    }

    bool isValid(String modelValue) =>
        modelValue.length > 5;
}
```